# Type '{ post: IPost; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IPost'. Property 'post' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IPost

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am working on a project to improve my skills in TS. Getting data from a server, everything is working fine. Posts started to be displayed without errors, However, when I decided to load the posts in individual Post.tsx components by mapping through the data ts immediately gave me an error:

```
    Type '{ post: IPost; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IPost'.
  Property 'post' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IPost'
```

The app is simple, there's the array of Posts which I fetch from the DB. I then map through the array and return the  components with the individual posts.

Here are the types I'm using:

```
interface IPosts {
  posts: IPost[]
};

interface IPost {
  _id: string
  title: string
}
```

Here is the code in Posts.tsx:

```
export default function Home({ posts }: IPosts) {    
  return (
      <div>
        {posts.map(post => {
          console.log(post);
          return (
            <Post key={post._id} post={post} />
          )
        })}
      </div>
  )
}
```

and here is the code for Post.tsx:

```
const Post = ( post : IPost) => { 
    console.log(post);
    return (
        <div>{post.title}</div>
    )
}
```

For some reason when I run this I get the error above on the post={post} prop I pass down to the Post component.

It also seems to convert a single post object like this:

```
{
 _id: "12345"
 title: "this is a title"
}
```

to this:

```
 {post: 
        {
         _id: "12345"
         title: "this is a title"
        }
    }
```

Although this is not ideal, I can destructure the post object in the Post component however it does not fix that error that keeps coming up :/

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

list declare by `type[]`

```
interface IPosts {
  posts: IPost[]
};
```

edit this also

```
 const Post = ( {post} : {post: IPost}) => {
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error :/ of:

Type '{ key: string; post: IPost; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IPost'.
  Property 'post' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IPost'.ts(2322)

Comment: @RuairidhGrass see the edited section please

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-4sxrxh?file=App.tsx

Comment: Excellent, thanks! this fixed it :D. 

do you know why the post object:

{
 _id: "12345"
 title: "this is a title"
}

became encapsulated like this?:

 {post: 
        {
         _id: "12345"
         title: "this is a title"
        }
    }

does this always happen when passing props into a component?

Comment: you need to define an attribute when passing data to the child. So the child can use that attribute to access the data.

Comment: can this be done from the parent? or is the only way to do it the way you showed here: ```const Post = ( {post} : {post: IPost}) => { ```

Comment: no. this is the way. But you can create a new interface for this `{post: IPost}`